# Simple Coding Problems

Tags: java

In the country of Rahmania, the cost of mailing a letter is 40 sinas for letters up to 30 grams. Between 30 g and 50 g, it is 55 sinas. Between 50 g and 100 g, it is 70 sinas. Over 100 g, it costs 70 sinas plus an additional 25 sinas for each additional 50 g (or part thereof). For example, 101 grams would cost 70 + 25 = 95 sinas. 149 g would also cost 95 sinas, because both of these packages only use the first 50 g over 100 g. Write a program that prompts the user for a mass and then gives the cost of mailing a letter having that mass.

This is the question and the only part I don't know how to do is the last part with the additional 25 sinas for each additional 50g.

Can someone show me how to write this part of the code?

I use netbeans btw.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double l;
l = input.nextInt();
x = l >= 100 / 50 * 25 + 70;
if (l <= 30) {
    System.out.println("40 Sinas");
}
if (l > 30 && l < 50) {
    System.out.println("55 Sinas");
}
if (l > 50 && l < 100) {
    System.out.println("70 Sinas");
}
if (l >= 100) {
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Here's the important part of the code. As you can see I need help on the last part.

Comment: Others won't do your homework for you but they will help you if you get stuck

Comment: Please read about how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular you should post the code you have already written, along with a description of the problem(s) you are having with it.

Comment: Not in the comments....you can edit your question and add the relevant code there.

Comment: This is mostly a math problem. After the first 100 grams, you need to charge for every additional 50 gram increment. How would you determine how many 50 gram intervals you have?

Comment: The letter mass minus 100 divided by 50?

Comment: A suggestion: it is not so good if we use `l` as variable name, because it look like `1`.

Comment: oh ok thanks, I was using it because of l in letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int l; // it should be int if read int
l = input.nextInt();
if (l <= 30) {
    System.out.println("40 Sinas");
}
if (l > 30 && l < 50) {
    System.out.println("55 Sinas");
}
if (l > 50 && l < 100) {
    System.out.println("70 Sinas");
}
if (l >= 100) {
    System.out.println(((((l - 100) / 50) + 1) * 25) + 70);
}
```

Comment: I have a question about the +1 why do we need that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `System.out.println(((int)(((l - 100) / 50) + 1) * 25) + 70);`

Comment: @Gordon l = 101; 101-100=1; 1/50=0 (integer division); 0+1=1; 1*25=25; 25+70=95; but of course there are also another form of calculation

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out, there is one major problem with Krayo's solution. If the weight value is exactly 100, using that calculation, you will in fact charge the customer an extra 25 sinas. This is caused by the `+ 1` portion of the calculation.

If the `weight` is 100, then the number of 50 gram intervals above 100 is 0 (`weight - 100 = 0`). Therefore, the customer shouldn't be charge anything, since the wording of the question says *Over 100 g...*. However, because you're adding 1, before performing the additional cost calculation, the customer gets dinged an extra 25 sinas needlessly.

Instead, in order to insure the correct amount for this, and all other cases, I would use the [Math.ceil(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) method instead. This method will round the value up to the nearest whole number. For example, 5.2 becomes 6.0, and 5.0 remains 5.0.

So your calculation would look like this instead:

```
int cost = (int) (Math.ceil((weight - 100) / 50.0f) * 25) + 70;
```

*Note that we need use a floating point value to ensure we end up with a decimal value. And since `Math.ceil` returns a double, we simply cast it back to an integer.*

This is a sample program to demonstrate this:

```
public class CalculationTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int weight = 100;

        int good_cost = (int) (Math.ceil((weight - 100) / 50.0f) * 25) + 70;
        int bad_cost = ((((weight - 100) / 50) + 1) * 25) + 70;

        System.out.println("Weight = " + weight + "g");
        System.out.println("Good cost calculation = $" + good_cost);
        System.out.println("Bad cost calculation = $" + bad_cost);
    }
}
```

*You can change the `weight` value to experiment.*

Which outputs:

> Weight = 100g 
>   Good cost calculation = $70 
>   Bad cost calculation = $95